# IIS7: View resources used by specific website

Tags: iis, iis-7, hosting

Is there a way to view the resources (RAM, CPU, etc) used by specific websites hosted in IIS?  Something like task manager, but specifically for IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch IIS manager and select your server name. In the features view, select 'worker processes', underneath the 'iis' section.  You can see all currently running app pools; if you double click on an app pool, you can see the current activity as well (nothing will show up if the site is under low load as it's processing it too fast to be material).

If you want more information, or you want to collect historical data, you're going to have to use performance monitor.

Comment: That gives me a snapshot, but I was hoping for more of a graph that updates... similar to task manager.  ah well...

Comment: Perfmon will do that, but I agree that it's not nearly as simple as 'right click, task manager' and you instantaneously see everything.